# Why does com.google.gson.Gson::toJson return an empty object?

Tags: java, json, model-view-controller, gson

A view model that I'm working on has a method like:

```
public String getModelJson() {
    final ItemModel model = this.getModel();
    if (model == null) {
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }

    final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    return gson.toJson(model);
}
```

This method relies on com.google.gson.Gson::toJson to serialize a POJO model to a JSON string that can be used in my view. Here's the model code:

```
public final class ItemModel extends ContentFragmentModel {
    
    @Expose
    private String error;

    @Expose
    private String id;

    @Expose
    private String name;

    public ItemModel(final ContentFragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    public String id() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String name() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getModelPath() {
        return "/path/to/model";
    }
}
```

When I call `getModelJson` from my view, the method always returns `{}`, even though I can prove that the model is being loaded correctly; if I rewrite the method like this:

```
public String getModelJson() {
    final ItemModel model = this.getModel();
    return model != null ? "{\"name\": \"" + model.getName() + "\"}";
}
```

...it returns the expected output: `{"name": "item name"}`, where `item name` is the name correctly loaded from the fragment.

How can I get the model to serialize correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem. Here's the code for the base model class:

```
public abstract class ContentFragmentModel {

  protected String error;

  private boolean isValid = false;

  public ContentFragmentModel(@NotNull final ContentFragment fragment) {
    final String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    if (fragment == null) {
      this.error = "No content fragment passed to " + className + ".";
      return;
    }

    final String fragmentModelPath = FragmentUtil.getFragmentModelPath(
      fragment
    );
    if (!fragmentModelPath.equals(this.getModelPath())) {
      this.error = "Invalid content fragment passed to " + className + ".";
      return;
    }

    this.loadElements(fragment);

    this.isValid = true;
  }

  public @NotNull String getError() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfBlank(this.error, StringUtils.EMPTY);
  }

  public boolean isValid() {
    return this.isValid;
  }

  protected abstract String getModelPath();
}
```

Notice that the base model class AND the model class have a member called `error`. In the base class, this member is `protected`. In the extended class, it's `private`. This apparently works in Java - the member in the child class hides the parent member - but this weird usage of class inheritance seems to break `com.google.gson.Gson::toJson`. There is no mention of this in [the docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html) for that method so I'm adding a post here to hopefully save some poor soul a couple hours if they run into the same issue I had.

The fix for me was just to remove the `error` member from the extending class. I found that it wasn't even really used for anything, so I just deleted it. If you are running into this with a member that can't be simply deleted, you might try renaming it so it doesn't collide with the member in the base class.